# Android studio: not able to see component in design view

Tags: android, android-studio, widget, components

I am not able to see the components in design view in order to be able to edit them/ resize/ relocate them, though i can see them in the component tree.[image]

Comment: What is the layout of these components? Hover over the warning the red exclamation in the component tree.

Comment: Please try File -> Invalidate caches / restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, click the red (!) icon at the top right corner of the visual editor and read about the cause. Mostly it is related to the fact that the entire project doesn't build correctly - which is required for the visual editor to display the content:

[image: an error indicator]

In less probable cases it can be related to the broken sync between the IDE and gradle scripts - a sync with gradle scripts fixes the issue in this case.

In rare cases it can be an issue of the IDE itself, then a restart of the Android Studio or cache reset helps: File -> Invalidate caches / restart.